# Join objects and keep bone weights

Tags: armature

I have an armature where each bone controls different object. When I try to join objects together I can control the new mesh with only one bone, the others are useless. How to avoid this?

Comment: I have now parented the objects with Armature Deform but after joining objects I'm still facing the same problems. The only option that seems to work is parenting with Automatic Weights but since the objects have pretty complex geometry I have to weight paint them on my own. Is there a way to paint the whole object with strength 1.0 without having to reach every corner of the object with a brush?

Comment: Yes my answer was partly incorrect, Armature Deform won't work, once your objects joined you can either parent With Automatic Weight if it's an organic object or parent With Empty Groups if it's a mechanical object, in the latter case you'll need to assign the vertices to the Vertex Group they are supposed to be part of in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, select the vertices, select the group, click Assign. But maybe show some pictures or share your file so that we can help more accurately?